# Angular not a known element - Template parse errors

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have just started with angular but i'm having trouble with angular picking up new components.

I've rebuilt already and restarted the server and nothing.

The app module file is as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { MessageComponent } from "./messages/message.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MessageComponent
    ],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

The app component html is nice and simple

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <app-message></app-message>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It's the app-message that angular can't find.

Message component is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-message',
    templateUrl: './message.component.html'

})
export class MessageComponent {

}
```

and message.component.html is as follows

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{message.content}}
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="author">
            {{message.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="config">
            <a href="">Edit</a>
            <a href="">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>
```

I'm getting template parse errors that as per image
[image: angular error]

Comment: try importing CommonModule as well

Comment: @SumitAgarwal why should he try that?

Comment: We are missing a piece of information. There are no errors in the code you shared now (except that `app-message` will fail, because of `message` being undefined and therefor `{{message.content}}` won't work. I suggest you take a good look if you have not made any typos.

Comment: I totally oversaw that, normally I get this error when I forget to declare/import an element in the module where I consume it

Comment: Thank you Pierre, I was adamant there was nothing wrong but in the message.model i mistyped "constructor". I feel like a fool but at least found it now. I also need to put on highlighting on the sublime. I assume there will be an angular package for it